# Undefined offset error in PHP loop

Tags: php

I was looking at my httpd error log and notice this error over and over again

> Undefined offset: 1 in /usr/home/*****/*****/*****/*****/index.php on line 43.

I was hoping someone could look over my code and see they see any problem which would be causing this error

```
<?php $files = scandir('movies/');
            foreach($files as $file) {
              if ($file === '.' or $file === '..') continue;
              $t = str_replace("-", " ", $file);
              $section = explode(';', $t);
              $section = explode('.', $section[1]);
              $t = explode(';', $t);
              $t = $t[0];
```

The line that is getting the error is

```
$section = explode('.', $section[1]);
```

The code is working on the site but giving an error

Comment: So, check if you have `$section[1]` before trying to explode it? Pretty straight forward.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and you are correct there are to files that had the wrong naming scheme. I just put a simple if statement to check if `$section[1]` was empty or not. I took care of the name problems as well. Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens, because after explode you have array only with `[0]` key probably, that means you have no `;` in your `$t` in previous line and whole `$t` goes into first `$section` assignment.

Never assume you will always have exactly the data you have during code developing. You're setting traps for yourselves. I would suggest solution close to following:

```
$section = explode(';', $t);
$section = explode('.', count($section) > 1 ? $section[1] : $section[0]);
```

or

```
$section = explode(';', $t);
if(count($section) === 0) {
    // debug code, warnings, reports, Exceptions etc.
} else {

}
```